# Very slow "portfolio" section of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, performance, categories

A client of mine is adding content to his Wordpress. The site is www.airsolid.ca.

He uses "portfolios" to add his different boat models. All seems fine except when we click "all boat models" in the section where it lists all items, it takes up to 30 seconds to load.

Here is the direct link to the section:

http://www.airsolid.ca/bateaux/

Any idea on what I could change to make it load under 3-5 seconds? I have a feeling it loads all images at once... and since there are many, it takes way too much time. Ironically, he doesn't even want the images to show when he lists them.

Answer (score 2):

Use https://tools.pingdom.com to monitor what's loading, how long it's loading, etc. You can see if images or scripts are holding it up.

Since the screen is white while it's loading, I'd imagine it's a query issue. You can use the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to help determine the cause.

I used pingdom and got these results: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/ekJpVY/http://www.airsolid.ca/bateaux/

It had 1 request until the ~22 second mark at which point the CSS/JS/Image requests came in, which means that it's not being held up by scripts or images.

The page is only ~2mb, which means it's not loading all the images either. I'd start with Query Monitor - it's definitely something server side, probably a faulty WP_Query or other issue in a PHP loop.